# How to use the Trello API to get all cards with a purple label?

Tags: trello

I'm trying to use Trello sandbox to get all cards (from all boards) that are labeled purple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
Trello.rest('GET', 'search', {'query': 'label:purple'});
```